# Create a segue and attach it between two view controllers through Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

How would we create a segue in swift programatically, without using Storyboards. I cannot use storyboards because of how the app is structured, so I need to know how to do it programatically.

Essentially, all I want to do is create a segue, and attach it between the source and the destination.

So far, I have created a RollSegue class which is a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue. Now, I'm trying to do the following:

```
var seg: RollSegue = UIStoryboardSegue("roll", self, destination)
```

and I have also tried:

```
var seg: UIStoryboardSegue = UIStoryboardSegue("roll", self, destination)
```

These lines of code run fine, but when I try to call the performSegue method, I get the error:

```
Receiver (<Home1: 0x7fc84b573fd0>) has no segue with identifier 'roll'
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can only set segue identifier on storyboard. So if you want to navigate between two controllers, you should use

`func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool)`

or

`func presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion completion: (() -> Void)?)`

Comment: Is there anyway I can have a custom animation play when switching between VCs?

Comment: Absolutely, you can search custom transition animations for more details.